# Why are my times not posted to the leaderboard?

Tags: grid-2

I went back into the Timeline to see if I could beat the times that my friends had set. When pressing Xbox <kbd>Y</kbd> to see the leaderboard I can see all my friends times there, but not my own. Pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> to 'Find myself' I get no results.

Why are my times not being posted to the leaderboard?
Are there specific conditions for the lap to be posted? Such as staying on the track and not riding curbs?

Or is it just the case that you cannot see yourself on the leaderboards?

**I've done some testing and I can't see my result on the leaderboard after the race, which is what I would expect**
[image: Race result]
[image: Leaderboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that was fixed in more recent patches. If you still encounter it, start with a new in-game profile.

Comment: So I have to start the game again from fresh? That's super lame.

Comment: Thanks for poking the question Community. I shall have to give this another try and see if it's resolved.